# Glide Process 'command 'git'' finished with non-zero exit value 128

Tags: android, git, gradle, android-glide

I have downloaded Glide from Github and wanted to test the program on Android studio. But once i Clean the project, i have this error

```
Information:Gradle tasks [clean]
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'glide-master'.
> Process 'command 'git'' finished with non-zero exit value 128
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 0.28 secs
Error:fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Settings file '/Users/MyComputer/Downloads/glide-master/settings.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'glide-master'.
> Process 'command 'git'' finished with non-zero exit value 128

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

what does the error mean? I have build using Gradle.it is because of version problem on Android studio?

Comment: I don't know the root cause, but it appears that a Gradle task is running some Git process, but it is running it from a directory outside the location of your Git repository.

Comment: Post your settings.gradle. The log talks about a git command. It is strange

Comment: probably you have moved your source code folder.

Answer (score 16):

Same error occurred for me also.

In build.gradle previous code like

```
exec {
        commandLine 'git', 'describe', '--tags'
    }
```

then I added `'cmd'` before `'git'`

and that error gone.

below is code after adding the code

```
exec {
        commandLine 'cmd', 'git', 'describe', '--tags'

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

This happen if `git` not configured properly with the `Android Studio` project.
And nobody seems experienced this before. Because I google thousand times and solutions not work.

What is just work for me:

- Solution for `Gradle Build Android Studio Project`
- Clone the project from `git`. Or Upload your project to `git` and clone `Fresh` in empty folder of your PC. (This is for configure `git` properly, other way did not work properly to my project)
- Delete if any `.idea` folder exists.
- Open as existing `Android Studio` project.
- Let it roll. If it require any dependency, continue with that.

Answer (score 4):

```
exec {
    commandLine "git", "submodule", "update", "--init", "--recursive"
}
```

Then I added `cmd` before `git`.

and that error gone.

```
exec {
    commandLine "cmd","git", "submodule", "update", "--init", "--recursive"
}
```

Comment: This may or may not work on Windows, but the OP uses Unix paths in his question, so this answer is unlikely to work for her or him.

Answer (score 2):

```
new ByteArrayOutputStream().withStream { os ->
    def result = exec {
        executable = 'git'
        args = ['log', '-1', '--pretty=format:%ct']
        standardOutput = os
    }

    return os.toString() + "000"
}
```

Change to the following code

```
new ByteArrayOutputStream().withStream { os ->
    def result = exec {
        executable = 'cmd'
        args = ['log', '-1', '--pretty=format:%ct']
        standardOutput = os
    }

    return os.toString() + "000"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this, it is the only answer that worked for me on OSX

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27100821/2587350

Answer (score 0):

In MAC OS redownload command-line tools and make sure that it is assigned to path.

A easy fix is to install Xcode and run a demo project. This sets up the dependencies properly.

Answer (score 0):

the process is executing in the gradle's own directory (`~/.gradle/x.y.z`)

use `cmd.execute([], project.projectDir)` with arguments

Answer (score 0):

In my case when I checked `git status` I got the following output:

```
fatal: unsafe repository ('/home/Documents/Examples/Example.App' is owned by someone else)
To add an exception for this directory, call:

git config --global --add safe.directory /home/Documents/Examples/Example.App
```

which I did and it worked :) (the path is just an example, but you will get your full path of the project)

Answer (score -1):

1. In Android Studio, File > New > Project from Version Control.
2. Use `your url` as URL, click the clone button.