# Process 'command 'git'' finished with non-zero exit value 128

Tags: android, git, android-studio, version-control

I need your help. I currently handle a project from my company about android app and i need to modify some feature in the app. Since the previous development was not handled by me, i only have the app in zip format. when i try to run it on android studio app, it says that **Process 'command 'git'' finished with non-zero exit value 128**.I tried to figure out the thing and i thought the problem is on the version control git but still i have not idea how to fix it.Hope you guys can help me.

[image]

Comment: Duplicated. See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27100088/command-git-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-128/27100821#27100821

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your project. There is a directory call ".git" It is a hidden directory. if it is not visible to active "show hide icons". Then delete that ".git" folder and try to build it again

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure Android Studio for Git:

https://javapapers.com/android/android-studio-git-tutorial/

Comment: Yes i tried that also but i stuck in the url part bcs i dont know the url since the developer has left. is there any other way?

Comment: Perhaps try one of these suggestions to remove the old Git repository?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31990372/remove-old-and-add-new-git-in-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

Gradle 7.5.1

In my case, that cause by the fork GitHub project not default contains upstream tags

with error `fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything.` is a git prompt

so I simply add try-catch surround with `exec` codes

Answer (score -1):

I got the same problem after downloading the vlc open source code then when I built the project: Process 'command 'git'' finished with non-zero exit value 128 error occurred. You have to configure git in Android studio. Go to VCS in android studio and enable it from there, then add your project to git, commit it, finally build again, see everything's sorted.