# How to run git command from gradle file in Github Actions?

Tags: android, git, gradle, github-actions

I have created a gradle closure to generate `versionName` for an Android Application from `git tag`. I can run it locally, however I cannot execute in a job of `GitHub Actions`. The machine is
`ubuntu-latest`.

Here is the closure and the error.

```java
ext.getVersionName = {
    try {
        def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
        exec {
            commandLine 'git', 'describe', '--tags', '--dirty'
            standardOutput = stdout
        }

        return stdout.toString().trim()
    } catch (ignored) {
        return null
    }
}
```

Error in Actions

```
> Process 'command 'git'' finished with non-zero exit value 128
```

How can I run this block in `Github Actions` ? Do you have any suggestions ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [command git finished with non-zero exit value 128](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27100088/command-git-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-128)

Comment: No, it does not. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Force it to check everything out:

```
- uses: actions/checkout@v2
  with:
    fetch-depth: 0
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. The problem was not fetching the tags.

Comment: I faced same issue. After this discussion I read GitHub actions documentation for checkout command again. And Found fetch-depth.

# Number of commits to fetch. 0 indicates all history for all branches and tags.
    # Default: 1
    fetch-depth: ''

This part is from Github Action checkout README.

Thanks Anthony Green